# Synonyms for "Inspect"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, programming

We have software which currently has these menu items: Map, Talk, Inspect, Analyze, Report, Team. We realize that the word *Inspect* word is not clear enough for most people. We have all the raw data shown on that part, plus filtering and some other features. It's not a log viewer or audit. It is somehow raw data, but in an organized way.

We are looking for a good replacement. We have options like "Input/Output", "Data and Traffic", but unfortunately none of them looks good enough in our case.

Does anyone have an idea what to replace the word *Inspect* with? Something more straight-forward, and more user-friendly (by which we mean that e.g. "Data" is good, but it's somehow scaring off users).

Comment: *Review*, perhaps, or *I/O Detail*? But  *Inspect* looks OK to me; at least a lot of graphics/video programs I use have "Data Inspectors" and the like. It only needs to be "clear" to the people actually looking for the data. What do they say when they talk about it or use it?

Comment: What distinguishes the options on the *Inspect* menu from those under *Analyze*?

Comment: Thanks Stoney for the comment! They're mainly confused to what to expect from this menu. Consider it would be unfamiliar for many people who doesn't know English very well.

Comment: @itsbruce it's a little bit hard to explain because you don't know too much about our software. In Analyze we have visualizations, but in Inspect it's all tables and text ...

Comment: I agree with @StoneyB; Inspect is just fine (oh for smarter users).  Hmm.  *View* ?

Comment: @itsbruce I agree with both of you ... __View__ seems so simple in this case, I guess ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remark that “In Analyze we have visualizations, but in Inspect it's all tables and text”.   Consider renaming *Analyze* to *Charts* or *Diagrams*, and *Inspect* to *Tables*.

More figuratively, consider terms like *facts, lowdown, nitty gritty, truth.*  These are nouns; it isn't clear from the tags you mentioned before whether you have a preference for using verbs rather than nouns for the tags.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and nice ideas! :) ... I guess I need to think about that, they seems works in our case, however still need to brainstorm it with friends to see how much it could be effective from the end-user prospective. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm accustomed to using...

> [drill down [into the data]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Whom%20the%20hell%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22drill%20down%20into%20the%20data%22&oq=%22drill%20down%20into%20the%20data%22&gs_l=serp.3...1211141.1216812.0.1217291.26.26.0.0.0.0.104.1673.24j2.26.0...0.0...1c.1.vSozMcyY6sI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1217&bih=864)

...in such contexts. In OP's context, I don't see a problem in discarding the space and calling it a [drilldown [facility]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Whom%20the%20hell%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22drilldown%20facility%22&oq=%22drilldown%20facility%22&gs_l=serp.3...7068.7773.3.8117.4.4.0.0.0.0.91.282.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.-wbIXI4Zgos&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1217&bih=864)

Comment: Thanks, I would discuss it with my colleagues. I personally like it, but I think a common word would be much better for the end-user. :)

Comment: Having been a statistical/business analysis programmer, I disagree your mode of correlating "drill down" with "inspect". "Drill down" could be seen as a subset of "inspect". Otherwise you would say the synonym of "mammal" is "human".

Comment: @Blessed Geek: I don't see what you mean. I was also a statistical/business analysis programmer for decades. I don't recall anyone every commenting on my use of *drilldown*, or failing to understand it. Possibly all the users I've dealt with have just been parroting back my own usage, but certainly in some contexts it's been "standard terminology". I don't see why anyone would think "Drill down" was a subset of "inspect" in the context of a computer application.

Comment: Object-oriented principles and set theory.